# Poweriteration for polynomials with roots that have the same absolute value

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

As far as I understand, the power iteration method calculates the eigenvalues of a matrix as long as the eigenvalues have distinct absolute values.
Is there anything that can be done about that condition? Especially in the case of companion matrices of polynomials.

Comment: You should clarify whether the question is about real polynomials and/or real roots.

Comment: You switch to sub-space iteration, Krylov space methods. Or apply a shift, to the matrix or to the polynomial. // The usual strategy for polynomial roots via a deflation approach is to start with the smaller roots by seeding the Newton or other higher-order iteration with points on a circle of the inner root radius. Why do you want to start with the largest roots? // Another name for your procedure is "Bernoulli iteration". // Note that a similar but better iteration is the core method of the Jenkins-Traub method.

Comment: @dxiv I am interested in methods for both the real and the complex case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your tips! Do you have a source that subspace iteration works on eigenvalues with same absolute value? I have read in several books, that it only works with eigenvalues that have differing absolute value, i.e. NUMERICAL METHODS FOR LARGE EIGENVALUE PROBLEMS by Y. Saad

Comment: @Ragon Power iteration won't work for multiple maximal moduli. Real polynomials have complex roots in pairs of conjugates that have the same modulus, so power iteration won't work for real polynomials whose roots of largest modulus are complex. That may or may not be a problem in your use-case. but you would need to provide more context.

Comment: The [Eigenvalue algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm) wikipedia page lists several algorithms (far from exhaustive) that might be useful.

Comment: @dxiv yes this is exactly the problem I am talking about and my question was if there is a way around this. For example calculating the eigenvalues of the companion matrix of the polynomial $x^5 + 1$.

Comment: @Ragon That's not a good example, since all roots have unit modulus. The answer to your question is that power iteration does not work out of the box as a good general-purpose root finder. The Jenkins-Traub algorithm, for example, which is loosely related to power iteration, has a step that specifically deals with the case of roots with equal-or-close moduli.

Comment: @dxiv thank you for your answer. At the moment I am reading myself into the jenkins traub algorithm and I already tried it with my example which works well. Interestingly it also can be implemented as a form of power iteration, but this is not really explained in detail in neither Jenkins and Traubs original paper nor the wikipedia article.